# width of the cell not resize after rotation with horizontal uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create uitableview and I display it horizontally with :

the cell `self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);`
the table `self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);`

When I open the tableview in portrait or landscape everything works O.K

The problems start when I'm rotating the device, the cell.frame/bounds are wrong.

From what I understand, the cell height is from heightForIndexPath
and the cell width is by the uitableview width.

the problem is, I think, the uitableview is setting the wrong value to the cell width.
I try many things, even tried just for the testing to set the bound or frame when I tap on some button, Just to see if I can get the uitableview to work o.k, but that did not work.

after the uitableview and uitableview transform, I can't control the cell position and fix this.

any ideas ?

Comment: Where do set this transforms? Is is viewDidLoad? Whats your self refer to?

Comment: @Greg 
the self is UIViewController.
the table transform is made after user interaction (button tap)
the uitableviewcell transform is made in the cell initWithFrame.

Comment: Is this: self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5); refer to UITableViewCell?

Comment: I haven't got too many information and I don't know it will work but you can try to set she default transform: cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; update the cell and apply transform (rotation) again.

Comment: @greg
I will try what you wrote.
I just came to update I set the UITableView(not the cell) to default transform when rotation starts, and set back the transform after the rotation ended, and that's ok (not perfect cause I hide the uitable while it rotate cause it's not look good when visible)

I will try to do it with the cell.
I wonder if this is must thing, a rule to turn off transform before rotation. thanks